# Why height=100% doesn't work?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I use a third-party component that occupies all the available space, i.e. `width=100%` and `height=100%`. I don't have control over it.

I'm trying to fit it in the following layout, but its `height=100%` doesn't work (I expect the third-party component to occupy all the green space).

[image]

Why? How would you fix that?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);
}

.third-party-component {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="third-party-component">
      Third party component
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The snippet is working as intended....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, for an element using percent on `height` to pick up its parent's height, the parent need a [height other than `auto` or being positioned absolute](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#the-height-property), or the `height` will be computed as `auto`.

Based on those 2 options, and as you mentioned in a comment, your own header is dynamic in height, you are left with absolute positioning.

The problem with adding absolute to the `content`, it will be taken out of flow and stop behaving as a normal flowed flex item, the good news, one can add a wrapper set to absolute.

Stack snippet

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.content {
  position: relative;                               /*  added  */
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);
}

.wrapper {
  position: absolute;                               /*  added  */
  left: 0;                                          /*  added  */
  top: 0;                                           /*  added  */
  right: 0;                                         /*  added  */
  bottom: 0;                                        /*  added  */
}

.third-party-component {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="third-party-component">
       Third party component
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Another option could be to update the Flexbox properties, to give the `content` a height, using `flex: 1 1 100%` and give `header` `flex-shrink: 0;` so it doesn't shrink (as `content` got 100%).

This might not work on Safari though, as I know it have had issues when the `height` property is not set, though can't test that now as I don't have access to Safari.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.content {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);
}

.third-party-component {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="third-party-component">
      Third party component
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `.content` haven't height (height = 0px) and `.third-party-component` have 100% of 0px. You can add propety `height : calc (100% - <height of .header>)` into `.content`

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.content {
  height: calc(100% - 18px);
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);
}

.third-party-component {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="third-party-component">
      Third party component
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Because `.content` haven't height (height = 0px) and `.third-party-component` have 100% of 0px. You can add propety `height : calc (100% - <height of .header>)` into `.content`

Comment: The thing is the height of the header is dynamic/unknown.

Comment: Example: height of `.header` is 20%, you have to set height of `.content` is 80% OR if unset height of `.header`, I thing that you should use JS to get height of `.header` then set propety height for `.content`

Comment: I see you got down voted (and not by me), and as that someone didn't told why, I will. The statements that _(height = 0px)_ and that the component have _100% of 0px_ is both wrong. Check my answer how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use another flex container in the `.content` element:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);
}

.third-party-component {
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="third-party-component">
      Third party component
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that you can't modify the third-party component, so adding `flex-grow: 1` to it doesn't count as a solution.

Comment: Defining css selectors and rules doesn't modify "a component". You can always do that. You can use a nesting selector if you don't want to target by class (`.content > div`, or some other variation) if that makes a difference to you.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but the whole point of this question is how to consume a third-party component without messing up with its styles.