# Angular component destroys flexbox height information for its child elements

Tags: html, angular, css, flexbox

I have a flexbox parent container whose `flex-grow` gives my containing `div` element as much height as is available. The children of this `div` element of course have `height:100%`.  This works fine.

```
<div style="display:flex; flex-direction:column;">
   <div style="flex-grow:1;background:green;"  id="parentContainer">

      <div style="height:100%;overflow:auto;background:red;"   id="contentContainer">
         <!-- content of whatever size confined to space allocated -->
      </div>

   </div>
</div>
```

But when I have an angular component in-between the parentContainer and contentContainer like so:

```
<div style="display:flex; flex-direction:column;">
   <div style="flex-grow:1;background:green;"  id="parentContainer">
    <my-ng-component style="height:100%; display:block; background:blue;">
      <div style="height:100%;overflow:auto;background:red;"   id="contentContainer">
         <!-- content of whatever size confined to space allocated -->
      </div>
    </my-ng-component>
   </div>
</div>
```

The angular component resets the height to 0px, so the contentContainer ends up with 0px height as well.

How do I fix the angular component to not destroy the height information?

Plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/0eai5HFZh7o2Vguzd5j6?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, `height: 100%` doesn't work properly on *child* of a *flex child*, and the main reason is that Flexbox *stretch* to fit its flex parent but still resolve its height to auto, as shown here in this answer:

- [Why height=100% doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46997591/2827823)

---

In your case though, when using flex *column* direction, it is possible.

The now used `flex-grow: 1` will leave the `flex-shrink` and `flex-basis` to their default, `1` and `auto`, and here it is the `auto` that cause the issue.

By changing it to, and here using the recommended shorthand `flex`, `flex: 1 100%` the child and its descendants will have a height to pick up their `100%` from.

*Note 1, simply using `flex: 1` (same as `flex: 1 1 0`) works too on Chrome/FF/Edge/IE11, but if I'm not wrong, Safari 10 had some issues when `flex-basis` becomes `0`.*

[Updated plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ojuVTxMxXjmpESGi3aqe?p=preview)

With the following updated code fragments

app.component.html

```
<div style="display:flex;flex-direction:column;height:324px;">
<div style="flex:1 100%;  background:black;  color: white;">
  foo
  <app-list style="height:100%;display:block; background:blue;"></app-list>
</div>
</div>
```